# Only the Settings page is broken

Tags: settings, mamp

I downloaded a fresh install of Craft 3.3.20.1 and ran it locally with MAMP. Everything works except that the Settings page gives me the error `This page isn’t working \n localhost didn’t send any data. \n ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`. Anything below the Settings page (eg `/settings/plugins`, `/settings/sections` etc) works fine. It's literally just Settings that is broken. I tried upgrading to 3.4.10.1 today and it didn't help.

An added weirdness is that if I reload the Settings page repeatedly, sometimes it will partially load. I have no idea what could cause such intermittent/partial loading. I noticed that I was below requirements on memory allocation and execution time, but when I edited my MAMP php.ini to bring them up to spec, it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: Do you have any plugins installed? Which ones, and what versions? (/admin/settings/plugins)

Comment: @BrandonKelly No plugins. The site is completely bare.

Comment: Try clearing your `storage/logs/` folder, and then go straight to `/admin/settings` and see if anything gets logged in there.

Comment: @BrandonKelly I logged in, deleted all the log files in /storage/logs and went directly to /admin/settings . It didn't create any new files. If I go to any other page, a web.log file gets created.

Comment: In that case, the request is likely not making it to Craft in the first place. Check your server configuration – you may have something like Suhosin installed that is interfering with the request.